# I am trying to figure out where a CDF F(x,y) is a bivariate CDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to figure out where a CDF $F(x,y)$ is a bivariate CDF. I know the properties that satisfy it is a bivariate CDF, I just do not know how to show they do not satisfy them (I know it is not a bivariate CDF).

One property suggest taking the limit with respect to $x$ and another mentions to take the limit with respect to $y$ then another mentions to take the limit of $F(x,y)$ but I do not know how to do this.

$$F(x,y)=\begin{cases} 0.25(x+y)^2 & \mbox{if }0 \leq x <1 \land 0 \leq y < 1
      \\ 0 &  \mbox{if }x<0 \lor y<0
      \\ 1 & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$F(x,y) = \lim\limits_{y\to-\infty} \begin{cases}
0.25(x+y)^2 & \mbox{if }0 \leq x <1 \land 0 \leq y < 1
       \\ 0 &  \mbox{if }x<0 \lor y<0
       \\ 1 & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

One of the properties you need to investigate is:

- $\forall x : \lim\limits_{y\to-\infty} F(x,y)=0$

Consider that as $y$ approaches $-\infty$, then $y<0$, so the limit is going to fall within the function's second piece.  The function is a constant in this piece, and that constant is $0$.

Thus clearly $\lim_{y\to-\infty} F(x,y)= 0$ and this is true for all values of $x$.

The next two properties can be proven similarly.

- $\forall y : \lim\limits_{x\to -\infty} F(x,y) =0$
- $\lim\limits_{\substack{x\to\infty\\y\to\infty}} F(x,y) = 1$

Can you handle these now?

---

Are you able to prove the CDF is monotonically non-decreasing in all of its arguments?  (And hence the probability measure in a subsection is always non-negative?

- $\forall \langle{x, y}\rangle, \forall \Delta x\geq 0, \forall \Delta y\geq 0 : F(x+\Delta x, y+\Delta y) - F(x,y) \geq 0 $

This follows by inspection.  As you increase $x$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, then $F(x,y)$ will either remain at $0$ (for $y<0$) or increase monotonously from $0$ to $1$.

Likewise for $y$, by symmetry.

---

Can also you prove the right continuity of both arguments?

- $\lim\limits_{0<h\to 0}F(x+h,y)=\lim\limits_{0<h\to 0}F(x,y+h)=F(x,y)$

The CDF is clearly continuous in the second and third piece.

$(x+y)^2$ is right continuous in the region $(x,y)\in[0,1)\times[0,1)$ as

$$\begin{align}\lim\limits_{0<h\to 0} ((x+h)+y)^2 & = \lim\limits_{0<h\to 0} (x+(y+h))^2
\\ & = \lim\limits_{0<h\to 0} (x+y)^2+2h(x+y)+h^2
\\ & = (x+y)^2
\end{align} $$

Note that the pieces are right continuous at the boundaries for both variables, though not always left continuous.

Comment: okay I can do all those except I am unclear how to do the continuity

Comment: I also do not know how to do the one above the continuity one. I did it in terms of x1 and x2 for x and y and am getting confused @GrahamKemp

Comment: The monotonicity condition you wrote is not sufficient for the measure to be non-negative. One needs a more sophisticated generalisation of monotonicity to $n$ dimensions. See counterexample and discussion on p7 of Rick Durrett's _Probability. Theory and Examples_, 4th ed (2010). In brief, the coordinate-wise monotonicity seems to guarantee non-negativity on "areas" and "lines", but does not preclude a negative mass at a point. I can't find a way to phrase it clearer, you might want to see the book.

Comment: Actually, Wikipedia has a remark on that matter: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Properties_2